# Lua making game loop and other functions

Tags: lua

So like i have mainloop and many other functions but i cant call them because of there is infinitive loop how can i make them so i can call the functions.

```
local socket = require("socket")

local function sleep(sec)
  socket.select(nil, nil, sec)
end

coroutine.wrap(function()
  while true do
    sleep(1)
  end
end)()
print("bob") -- like here
```

like in code it doesn't print bob because there is loop is way avoid that i tried using corountines but they didnt work

Comment: Your problem is your sleep function. You would have to implement a task scheduler of sorts

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would suggest using non-blocking commands, but I'm not certain what socket.select is doing.  It appears you are misusing it as a blocking timer.

Comment: what are u suggesting ?

Comment: @Quiloos39 your custom "sleep" function seems to be a blocking command; that is, the code completely stops until it completes.  Instead of pausing it, I would find an alternative.  However, I'm not entirely certain what socket.select _does_ so I can't say this will work.